# List files in a folder in natural order using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, ffmpeg

I am trying to merge several flv files using `ffmpeg`. `ffmpeg` requires a list of files in this format:

```
file '/path/to/file1'
file '/path/to/file2'
file '/path/to/file3'
```

With some search and trials, I have came up with this one line command:

```
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i <(for entry in "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")"; pwd)/$(basename "$1")"/*.flv;do echo "file '$entry'";done) -c copy output.flv
```

The script in brackets will generate a list of paths to all files in current folder in the format that is required by `ffmpeg`:

```
for entry in "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")"; pwd)/$(basename "$1")"/*.flv;do echo "file '$entry'";done
```

However, this only list files in alphanumeric order:

```
6846641-10.flv
6846641-11.flv
6846641-12.flv
6846641-13.flv
6846641-14.flv
6846641-15.flv
6846641-16.flv
6846641-17.flv
6846641-18.flv
6846641-19.flv
6846641-1.flv
6846641-20.flv
6846641-21.flv
6846641-22.flv
6846641-23.flv
6846641-24.flv
6846641-2.flv
6846641-3.flv
6846641-4.flv
6846641-5.flv
6846641-6.flv
6846641-7.flv
6846641-8.flv
6846641-9.flv
```

To merge videos correctly, I need files to be listed in natural order like this:

Naturally ordered files

[image]

As shown in the picture, files need to be sorted by the number after `-` from 1 to 24, with `6846641-1.flv` in the first line and `6846641-24.flv` in the last line. And each line in the format like this:

```
file '/mnt/c/Users/Oho/Desktop/save//6846641-xx.flv'
```

Would it be possible to generate a correctly formatted list for `ffmpeg` with bash script (and in one line if achievable)?

Edit: 
Thanks to Cyrus, the modified code is here and it does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
for entry in "$(cd "$(dirname "$1")"; pwd)/$(basename "$1")"/*.flv
do 
    echo "file '$entry'" >> fileOutputList.temp
done
sort -t "-" -n -k 2 fileOutputList.temp > fileOutputListSorted.temp
ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i fileOutputListSorted.temp -c copy output.flv
rm fileOutputList.temp
rm fileOutputListSorted.temp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
sort -t "-" -n -k 2 file
```

---

> `-t "-"`: use `-` as separator
>
> `-n`: compare according to string numerical value
>
> `-k2,2`: start a key at column 2